# Data blending with BI Engine in Data Studio

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio, google-bi-engine

Does BI Engine work for blended data sources?

I don't see any icons for visualisations using blended data sources.

Comment: do you mean [SESSION_USER()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/security_functions#session_user) function?

Comment: hmm, I acutally mean:
1) "filter by email" option in Data Studio
or
2) "enable user parameter" while connecting to the source

Comment: Mikhail I changed my question a little bit, I am curious about what's above

Answer (score 0):

As per [Filter by email address](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9713766?hl=en) documentation, you can create an email filter by following the steps:

1. Edit your data source.
2. In the upper left, click FILTER BY EMAIL.
3. Turn on Filter data by viewer email.
4. Select the field in your data source that contains viewer email addresses.
5. To return to the data source editor, click ALL FIELDS.

You should also be aware of **Limits of filter by email** found on [Filter by email address](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9713766?hl=en).

I recommend for you to check this [Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/bi-engine/docs/getting-started-data-studio#step_five_creating_a_chart) and let me know if you have other questions.